# nimbus look and feel not appear after creating jar

Tags: java, look-and-feel, nimbus

nimbus look and feel not appear after creating jar 
when i run program in NetBeans at time Nimbus look & Feel work perfectly but when i create Jar and run Application from jar at  time nimbus look & feel is not appear
CODE:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

     boolean isNimbus = false;
try {

    for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels())
    {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName()))
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            isNimbus = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!isNimbus)
    {
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Dashboard dashboardObj = new Dashboard();
}
```

Comment: Get the `java.version` in the code, and report what it says for the IDE and Jar.  I would guess the IDE is set up to use a version equal to or later than 1.6.0_10, while the Jar uses a version before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works fine in NetBeans, but the LAF does not appear, when running a jar file, it probably means that the LAF library wasn't correctly discovered in the classpath. Since I don't know your setup, I can't really suggest the right answer. You could adjust your classpath settings when running the jar file (via `jar -cp ...`) or package your application as a *single jar*, with all the dependencies included - [onejar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) is a convenient way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Nimbus, a cross platform look and feel introduced in the Java SE 6 update. So check that you are compile your java code in jdk 6 and run it in jre 6

type this in cmd:

java -version

to check current version of your jre